# How to get the speed of my navigation in Sygic

Tags: swift, sygic, sygic-mobile-sdk, sygic-maps

My issue is simple I am able to start a navigation, get the remaining time and distance from current position to end of route but I didn't find how to get the current speed of my navigation

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: I tried to find a solution but there is nothing in their documentation that help or explain how to get the speed of a navigation there is only how to get the current speed limit and it properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to get current speed and other info related to your GPS position is to use `SYPositioning`.

You will need to register your class as a `SYPositioningDelegate` and then update current speed in delegate method `SYPositioningDelegate.positioning(_ positioning: SYPositioning, didUpdate position: SYPosition)`

```
SYPositioning.shared().delegate = self

...

func positioning(_ positioning: SYPositioning, didUpdate position: SYPosition) {
    let currentSpeed = position.speed
    print("current speed is \(Int(currentSpeed))km/h")
}
```